# Different alignments for <label> and <input> inside form-group

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to use different alignments inside the `form-group`,
i want the label to be in the left and input in the right, `justify-content-start` ,  `justify-content-center` and `justify-content-end` doesn't work inside `<div class="form-group">`

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <form method="POST">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-borderless border border-dark">
    
    <tbody>
        <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
      <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-end">
        <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-end">
        <label for="date">Date. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-end">
        <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-end">
        <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-end">
        <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
    <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="date">Date. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
  </div>  
  </form>
  </div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Class Name on `form-group` `justify-content-end` to `justify-content-between`

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <form method="POST">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-borderless border border-dark">
    
    <tbody>
        <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
      <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
        <label for="date">Date. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
    <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="date">Date. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-center">
        <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
  </div>  
  </form>
  </div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *justify-content-between*

Try following code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <form method="POST">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-borderless border border-dark">
    
    <tbody>
        <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
      <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="date">Date. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
    <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="date">Date. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled>
        </div>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
  </div>  
  </form>
  </div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too! is it necessary to add d-flex into form-group?

Comment: No, you can remove. it will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

We need to do two things.

1. Use `justify-content-between` on the `.form-group`.
2. And also give `flex` property to both the label and `.form-control` in order for the spacing between being used up and to make it look good.

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    flex: 8;
  }

  .form-inline label {
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-borderless border border-dark">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="date">Date. :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="date"
                      disabled
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-6 border border-dark">
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">DELIVERY NOTE NO. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="date">Date. :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="date"
                      disabled
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">Purchase Order No. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">Mode Of Despatch. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="form-group d-flex form-inline justify-content-between"
                  >
                    <label for="del">Vehicle No. :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" disabled />
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```